# Row Means based on Column Substring

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame("CB_1.1"=c(0,5,6,2), "CB_1.16"=c(1,5,3,6), "HC_2.11"=c(3,3,4,5), "HC_1.12"=c(2,3,4,5), "HC_1.13"=c(1,0,0,5))

> df
  CB_1.1 CB_1.16 HC_2.11 HC_1.12 HC_1.13
1      0       1       3       2       1
2      5       5       3       3       0
3      6       3       4       4       0
4      2       6       5       5       5
```

I would like to take the mean of rows that share substring of the column name, before the ".". Resulting in a dataframe like this:

```
  CB_1 HC_2 HC_1
1  0.5    3  1.5
2  5.0    3  1.5
3  4.5    4  2.0
4  4.0    5  5.0
```

You'll notice that the column `HC_2.11` values remain the same, because no other column has `HC_2` in this dataframe.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) apply/tapply** For each row use tapply on it using an INDEX of the name prefixes and a function  `mean`.  Transpose the result.  No packages are used.

```
prefix <- sub("\\..*", "", names(df))
t(apply(df, 1, tapply, prefix, mean))
```

giving this matrix (wrap it in data.frame(...) if you need a data frame result):

```
     CB_1 HC_1 HC_2
[1,]  0.5  1.5    3
[2,]  5.0  1.5    3
[3,]  4.5  2.0    4
[4,]  4.0  5.0    5
```

**2) lm**  Run the indicated regression. The +0 in the formula means don't add on an intercept. The transpose of the coefficients will be the required matrix, `m`.  In the next line make the names nicer. `prefix` is from (1).  No packages are used.

```
m <- t(coef(lm(t(df) ~ prefix + 0)))
colnames(m) <- sub("prefix", "", colnames(m))
m
```

giving this matrix

```
     CB_1 HC_1 HC_2
[1,]  0.5  1.5    3
[2,]  5.0  1.5    3
[3,]  4.5  2.0    4
[4,]  4.0  5.0    5
```

This follows from the facts that (1) the model matrix X contains only ones and zeros and (2) distinct columns of it are orthogonal.  The model matrix is shown here:

```
X <- model.matrix(~ prefix + 0) # model matrix
X
```

giving:

```
  prefixCB_1 prefixHC_1 prefixHC_2
1          1          0          0
2          1          0          0
3          0          0          1
4          0          1          0
5          0          1          0
attr(,"assign")
[1] 1 1 1
attr(,"contrasts")
attr(,"contrasts")$prefix
[1] "contr.treatment"
```

Because the columns of the model matrix `X` are orthogonal the coefficient corresponding to any column for a particular row, y, of `df` (column of `t(df)`) is just `sum(x * y) / sum(x * x)` and since `x` is a 0/1 vector that equals the mean of the values of `y` corresponding to the 1's in `x`.

**3) stack/tapply**  Convert to long form inserting an `id` column at the same time.  Then use `tapply` to convert back to wide form tapply-ing `mean`.  No packages are used.

```
long <- transform(stack(df), ind = sub("\\..*", "", ind), id = c(row(df)))    
with(long, tapply(values, long[c("id", "ind")], mean))
```

giving this table. Wrap it in `as.data.frame.matrix` if you want a data.frame.

```
   ind
id  CB_1 HC_1 HC_2
  1  0.5  1.5    3
  2  5.0  1.5    3
  3  4.5  2.0    4
  4  4.0  5.0    5
```

Comment: Thank you! Why are you adding a 0 in the regression example?

Comment: I'm just confused as how the regression example computes the mean.

Comment: Have added clarifications to (2).

Answer (score 2):

- Here is a base R solution using `rowMeans` + `split.default`, i.e.,

```
dfout <- as.data.frame(Map(rowMeans, split.default(df,factor(s <- gsub("\\..*$","",names(df)), levels = unique(s)))))
```

such that

```
> dfout
  CB_1 HC_2 HC_1
1  0.5    3  1.5
2  5.0    3  1.5
3  4.5    4  2.0
4  4.0    5  5.0
```

- If you do not mind the order of column names, you can use the shorter code below

```
dfout <- as.data.frame(Map(rowMeans,split.default(df,gsub("\\..*$","",names(df)))))
```

such that

```
> dfout
  CB_1 HC_1 HC_2
1  0.5  1.5    3
2  5.0  1.5    3
3  4.5  2.0    4
4  4.0  5.0    5
```

Answer (score 1):

One option involving `dplyr` and `purrr` could be:

```
map_dfc(.x = unique(sub("\\..*$", "", names(df))),
        ~ df %>%
         transmute(!!.x := rowMeans(select(., starts_with(.x)))))

  CB_1 HC_2 HC_1
1  0.5    3  1.5
2  5.0    3  1.5
3  4.5    4  2.0
4  4.0    5  5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

A base option could be:

```
#find column names splitting on "."

cols <- unique(sapply(strsplit(names(df),".", fixed = T), `[`, 1))

#loop through each column name and find the rowMeans

as.data.frame(sapply(cols, function (x) rowMeans(df[grep(x, names(df))])))

  CB_1 HC_2 HC_1
1  0.5    3  1.5
2  5.0    3  1.5
3  4.5    4  2.0
4  4.0    5  5.0
```